# Required Field Validator for textbox having onblur value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a textbox having onblur value. When applying it, its corresponding Required Field Validator is not working. My code is here

```
 <div align="center">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_age" runat="server" 
       onfocus="if (this.value == 'Select Age') this.value = '';" 
       onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Select Age';" 
       value="Select Age" >
    </asp:TextBox>                          
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="req_tb_age" 
      controltovalidate="tb_age" errormessage="*" SetFocusOnError="True" 
      Display="Dynamic" />
    <asp:Button ID="bt_show" runat="server"   text="Show"
       CausesValidation="true"  
  onclick="bt_show_data_Click" OnClientClick="Confirm()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: what is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @borissh said you can use `placeholder` attribute, if you dont want to use `placeholder` you can add attribute `InitialValue="Select Age"` to your `RequiredFieldValidator` control.

You can study more on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using your onfocus/onblur events use `placeholder="Select Age"` attribute for the TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

The possible problem is that the code loops through all the validators but does not compare the ones that reference the same control at once.

try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477219/issue-with-chaining-required-field-and-regular-expression-validators-for-textbox) solution

Answer (score 0):

generally, the **RequiredFieldValidator** gets triggered by the **onChange** event at the client side. But you are trying to achieve the same by **onBlur** event. Yoy need to add this snippet to trigger the validator for **onBlur** Instead-

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtSummary.Attributes.Add("onblur", "ValidatorValidate(" + reqvalSummary.ClientID + ")");
}
```

Hope this helps. Or, go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069001/required-field-validator-not-working) to find out more on this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing inline JS you should write your all JS code in one place. External file is the best way to manage code though you can write file specific JS on same page.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb_age" runat="server" 
       onfocus="Validate(this)" 
       onblur="Validate(this)" 
       value="" >
 </asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function Validate(elem)
   {
     if (elem.value == '') 
     {
       elem.value = 'Select Age';
     }
   }
</script>
```